# C# OPOS printing next to a bitmap on a rotated receipt

Tags: c#, printing, receipt, opos, pos

This problem concerns a thermal receipt printer. I have downloaded C# EPSON OPOS receipt printing examples in attempt to implement such a printer in my current project, all is working well but when I print a bitmap logo, successive text is being printed under it, and I need to print some text to the right side of it. Here is an approximation of what it does now:
[image: Before]
This is what I need it to do:
[image: After]
My current code, pretty much as-is from EPSON's samples:

```
private void btnReceipt_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //<<<step8>>>--Start
    //Initialization
    DateTime nowDate = DateTime.Now;                            //System date
    DateTimeFormatInfo dateFormat = new DateTimeFormatInfo();   //Date Format
    dateFormat.MonthDayPattern = "MMMM";
    string strDate = nowDate.ToString("MMMM,dd,yyyy  HH:mm",dateFormat);
    int iRecLineSpacing;
    int iRecLineHeight;
    bool bBuffering = true;

    bool bBitmapPrint = false;
    int iPrintRotation = 0;


    string strCurDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    string strFilePath = strCurDir.Substring(0, 
    strCurDir.LastIndexOf("Step8") + "Step8\\".Length);
    strFilePath += "bitmap_logo.bmp";


    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

    Rotation[] arBitmapRotationList = m_Printer.RecBitmapRotationList;
    Rotation[] arBarcodeRotationList = m_Printer.RecBarCodeRotationList;

    //Check rotate bitmap
    for (int i = 0; i < arBitmapRotationList.Length; i++)
    {
        if (arBitmapRotationList[i].Equals(Rotation.Left90))
        {
            bBitmapPrint = true;
            iPrintRotation = (iPrintRotation | (int)PrintRotation.Left90)
                | ((int)PrintRotation.Bitmap);
        }
    }

    iRecLineSpacing = m_Printer.RecLineSpacing;
    iRecLineHeight = m_Printer.RecLineHeight;

    if (m_Printer.CapRecPresent == true)
    {
        try
        {
            m_Printer.TransactionPrint(PrinterStation.Receipt, PrinterTransactionControl.Transaction);

            m_Printer.RotatePrint(PrinterStation.Receipt, (PrintRotation)iPrintRotation);


            if (bBitmapPrint == true)
            {
                m_Printer.PrintBitmap(PrinterStation.Receipt, strFilePath, m_Printer.RecLineWidth, PosPrinter.PrinterBitmapCenter);
            }

            m_Printer.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt,"\u001b|4C" + "\u001b|bC" + "   Receipt     ");

            m_Printer.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt,"\u001b|3C" + "\u001b|2uC" + "       Mr. Brawn\n");

            m_Printer.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt,"\u001b|2uC" + "                                                  \n\n");

            m_Printer.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt,"\u001b|2uC" + "\u001b|3C" + "        Total payment              $" +"\u001b|4C" + "21.00  \n");

            m_Printer.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt,"\u001b|1C\n" );

            m_Printer.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt,strDate + " Received\n\n");

            m_Printer.RecLineHeight = 24;
            m_Printer.RecLineSpacing = m_Printer.RecLineHeight;

            m_Printer.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt,"\u001b|uC" + " Details               \n");

            m_Printer.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt,"\u001b|1C" + "                          " + "\u001b|2C" + "OPOS Store\n");

            m_Printer.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt,"\u001b|uC" + " Tax excluded    $20.00\n");

            m_Printer.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt,"\u001b|1C" + "                          " + "\u001b|bC" + "Zip code 999-9999\n");

            m_Printer.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt,"\u001b|uC" + " Tax(5%)        $1.00" + "\u001b|N" + "    Phone#(9999)99-9998\n");
        }
        catch(PosControlException ex)
        {
            if(ex.ErrorCode == ErrorCode.Illegal && ex.ErrorCodeExtended == 1004)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to print receipt.\n", "Printer_SampleStep8", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

                // Clear the buffered data since the buffer retains print data when an error occurs during printing.
                m_Printer.ClearOutput();
                bBuffering = false;
            }
        }

        try
        {
            m_Printer.RotatePrint(PrinterStation.Receipt, PrintRotation.Normal);

            if(bBuffering == true)
            {
                m_Printer.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt, "\u001b|fP");
            }

            m_Printer.TransactionPrint(PrinterStation.Receipt, PrinterTransactionControl.Normal);
        }
        catch(PosControlException)
        {
            // Clear the buffered data since the buffer retains print data when an error occurs during printing.
            m_Printer.ClearOutput();
        }
    }

    m_Printer.RecLineSpacing = iRecLineSpacing;
    m_Printer.RecLineHeight = iRecLineHeight;
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
    //<<<step8>>>--End
}
```

If there is a method to do absolute text positioning or being able to write to the same line where the bitmap is, it would solve my issue. Any directions appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Please ask EPSON whether you can print with the layout you want with one set of RotatePrint.

As an alternative, consider dividing it into two sets of RotatePrint.

If you first set of RotatePrint with Bitmap and "Some other text", and the second set of RotatePrint with "Sample text 1" to "Sample text 3", it will be close to the layout you want.

---

#### In addition:

Epson OPOS seems to support PageMode, so can you print it?

As for [explanation of Japanese](https://faq2.epson.jp/web/Detail.aspx?id=036240), please look through google translation etc.

Comment: I think this way will defeat the purpose of rotated print, as "Some other text" part will be cut off at the point of second RotatePrint section, and I would like it to be very long. Do you know of a reilable way to contact them about this?

Comment: As you pointed out, "Some other text" part is split. Since it is inevitable, you need to devise a layout so that it will not be ugly. I received a similar question when I worked in manufacturer(not EPSON), and responded as described above. Please send an e-mail to the contact address from EPSON's support page or register as a user and get support. Contacts are divided for each model, for example, TM-T88V is [here](https://epson.custhelp.com/app/ask/p_model_name/Epson%20TM-T88V). User registration will be one [here](https://www.onlineregister.com/epson/m/reg/).